# Google assistant is not detecting my application

Tags: android, flutter, google-assistant, app-actions

I'm trying to implement google assistant app actions in the flutter.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions-2#0 I'm referring to this link and building the application.

I have uploaded the signed bundle to the play console internal testing and also created the **shortcuts.xml** and linked it to **AndroidManifest.xml** too.

The google assistant app actions tool in the android studio is creating the app actions preview and also when I run the app action from the app action tool in the android studio the app is performing the action I have specified but when I give a voice command like "**okay google, show Tasks in the Test app**" the google assistant is not opening my test app and performing the action I have specified. Google Assistant is waking up when I say **okay, google**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the preview in the test tool, make sure you specify the App name. Although it is listed as "optional", I find that specifying a name that is unlikely to match any other application makes sure that it will match while testing. (I usually use a name such as "bogus" or "fake".)

[image: Picture of App Actions Test Tool]

Comment: The tool automatically gives "test app action" name when I create the preview but the app actions didn't work. When I gave a name like you suggested it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you need to run the app from the android directory to be able to use the google assistant plugin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).